# Can not put a div in center (margin:0 auto; doesn't work)

Tags: html, css

I want to put a div in center (horizontally).
At the same time, I want to put that div margin-top:40px and margin-bottom:20px.
But once I assigned margin:0 auto, margin-top and bottom does not work.

```css
#circle_price {
  background-color: red;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: red;
  -moz-border-radius: 50px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 50px;
  margin-top: 40px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Anyone has an idea about this? Thanks.

Comment: Can you post the actual code you're using? The order might be relevant and also any other elements that might be affecting it

Comment: I got this already. Thanks a lot Lynch !

Comment: No worries, was the problem I thought in the end!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`margin: 0 auto` which is equal to `margin: 0 auto 0 auto` will override your earlier set properties i.e. margin-top and margin-bottom is reset to 0.

You need to use `margin: 40px auto 20px auto` which is short hand for `margin-top` `margin-right` `margin-bottom` and `margin-left` in clockwise order.

```css
.center-me {
  margin: 40px auto 20px auto;
  width: 300px;
  background: lightblue;
}
```

```html
<div class="center-me">Centered block</div>
```

Comment: Ah, thanks a lot. This is much better! very useful. :)

Comment: No problem :) You posted an answer as well, it worked because your bottom properties are overriding the above properties. But it is much better to shorten your CSS rules when you code in the long run :)

Answer (score 0):

```
margin: 0 auto;
margin-top: 20px;
margin-bottom: 100px;
```

it works.

Comment: Please elaborate on this (and why it works) to flesh it out into a full answer. Thanks!